# Buck converter chip blowing

Tags: buck, solenoid

I recently designed a buck converter according to the specifications of the chip manufacturer, but for some reason the buck converter chip blows up.

I have a Meanwell power supply (HLG-600H-48A) that feeds the buck converter. 5 V is expected at the output of the buck converter.

The 5 V and the 48 V are then connected to a daughter board where a MOSFET switches a solenoid. Everything works well when I only use the 5 V, but as soon as I deliver 48 V the chip of the buck converter blows up.

Does anyone have any comments or ideas about this?

Buck converter:

[image]

Solenoid driver:

[image]

Solenoid presence detection:
[image]

Layout buck:

[image]

Edit: The issue is fixed by placing another capacitor at the Vin pin of the buck converter chip. We saw a lot of interference and harmonics on the Vin signal. Now it's happy and working.

Comment: Does this happen under load? Did you run the design rule check in kicad before ordering the pcb (in case this is on a pcb)?

Comment: @SimSon no solenoid is connected but there is a 5 -> 3v3 linear regulator for powering a mcu on the daugtherboard but the strange thing is that it only happens when the 48v is applied to the daughterboard

Comment: How do you solder the circuit? By hand, or reflow? Is there a chance that you get short circuits due to flux on the pcb? From my experience, this converter (I'm working with one of its brothers) does not easily die due to the internal protection machanisms... so if the design and assembly is done correctly, it should be hard to kill.

Comment: @SimSon It's done by reflow and thé design rules are taken into account

Comment: Can you post a layout of your design?

Comment: @HansPeterLoft unfortunately I can not

Comment: It might be a bad layout, so you definitely should post a layout here, also if it is only the buck converter alone

Comment: @HansPeterLoft i have added a layout of the bug converter

Comment: Does the regulator die when you connect the 48V to the daughter board, or does it die when the solenoid is activated (or deactivated?)

Comment: The main board is active when the daughterboard is connected to 48V?  Don't know how far they are, but you have 3.3uF right next to the regulator, and then introduce another 10uF at the far end of an inductive path; that might put some spikes on your input.  Maybe try taking out C5 and increasing C17.

Comment: Layout isn’t ideal and 48 is too close to 60 V for my comfort, but not enough to break immediately. Can you try to probe Vin, boot and PH at lower input voltage and post an oscillogram?

Comment: Did I get that right: the converter board gets its supply from the daughter boards and the 5V are then fed back to the daughter board? If so, are the boards already connected on power-up (vs. hotswapping)? I wonder if the problem could be with the load or how your subcircuits work together..

Comment: I wouldn't use thermal relief for connections that are meant to act as heatsinks. The regulator could have a better heatsink with solid copper pours. Same for the diode.

Comment: Oh, and the feedback network should be connected to the output *behind* the output capacitors (clipped in your picture).

Comment: @SimSon the converter board gets fed from the power supply and then the 48v and 5v gets connected trough wires to the daughter boards aprox. 2m of wire is used. Also worth to mention is that there are 2-16 daughter boards connected to the converter board. but in my tests i only use 2. I'm going to take a look at the total capacitance also a good mention for connecting the feedback loop after the capacitors.

Comment: Please draw a block diagram of what and how things are connected. It’s unclear at the moment.

Comment: EN pin seems specified between 1.15V and 1.36V, you put ~1.5V there. What's the logic behind that? Are those 1% resistors? Better? Worse? Also the TI datasheet 3V3 output example placed 124k + 30.1k there which I don't understand at all.

Comment: C17 should be closer to the chip with priority over the EN resistors. The thermal reliefs also sabotage the ground return paths somewhat.